# I am having trouble with my reference page in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I am doing a Beamer presentation and my reference page won't load. Here is my code that I am using

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Master.bib}


\begin{frame}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

and here is what my `Master.bib` looks like

```
@article{hafsteinsson2009porous,
Author = {Hafsteinsson, Haukur Elvar},
Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
Journal = {Chalmers University of Technology, Gothenburg},
Title = {Porous media in OpenFOAM},
Year = {2009}}

@article{domaingo2016semi,
Author = {Domaingo, Andreas and Langmayr, Daniel and Somogyi, Bence and Almbauer, Raimund},
Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
Journal = {Transport in Porous Media},
Number = {2},
Pages = {451--466},
Publisher = {Springer},
Title = {A Semi-implicit Treatment of Porous Media in Steady-State CFD},
Volume = {112},
Year = {2016}}
```

I have done everything that I could find which was not using the  `\bibliography{Master.bib}` tag and use it directly into the reference frame but that still didn't work and I also changed around `\bibliographystyle{•}` but when I don't have it in I don't get any errors and it builds it but without any references on the page. I have done PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, as well and that didn't help with my issue. I also do have the `Master.bib` in the same directory as all of my `.tex` files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) (and the classic [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` has its own data backend processor, `biber`, which is the default when you don't specify anything:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

hence, you have to compile your document with: `pdflatex > biber > pdflatex > pdflatex`, notice the `biber` instead of `bibtex` (this is the best solution).

If you use `arara`, it does it for you (the first 4 line here are necessary only if you use it):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents}{Master.bib}
    @article{hafsteinsson2009porous,
        Author = {Hafsteinsson, Haukur Elvar},
        Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
        Journal = {Chalmers University of Technology, Gothenburg},
        Title = {Porous media in OpenFOAM},
        Year = {2009}}

    @article{domaingo2016semi,
        Author = {Domaingo, Andreas and Langmayr, Daniel and Somogyi, Bence and Almbauer, Raimund},
        Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
        Journal = {Transport in Porous Media},
        Number = {2},
        Pages = {451--466},
        Publisher = {Springer},
        Title = {A Semi-implicit Treatment of Porous Media in Steady-State CFD},
        Volume = {112},
        Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{Master.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second best solution, if you want to use the `bibtex` backend processor, is to write:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and compile with: `pdflatex > bibtex > pdflatex > pdflatex` (or, if you use `arara`, adding the first 4 lines you find here):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents}{Master.bib}
    @article{hafsteinsson2009porous,
        Author = {Hafsteinsson, Haukur Elvar},
        Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:13:42 +0000},
        Journal = {Chalmers University of Technology, Gothenburg},
        Title = {Porous media in OpenFOAM},
        Year = {2009}}

    @article{domaingo2016semi,
        Author = {Domaingo, Andreas and Langmayr, Daniel and Somogyi, Bence and Almbauer, Raimund},
        Date-Added = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2017-04-03 05:12:59 +0000},
        Journal = {Transport in Porous Media},
        Number = {2},
        Pages = {451--466},
        Publisher = {Springer},
        Title = {A Semi-implicit Treatment of Porous Media in Steady-State CFD},
        Volume = {112},
        Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{Master.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, in your case, the output is the same:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response I have written down what you gave but when I build it I get the following error:   `Error : could not start the command : "/Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex" "Math Presentation".aux` If it does make a difference I am using TexMaker on a Mac, but I figured it shouldn't overly. And I do have the proper paths set up for Mac as well for TexMaker

Comment: @Robert In your question you said you have run PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX. You only need to run PDFLaTeX, **Biber**, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX with your original document. Delete the auxiliary files before doing it.

Comment: My apologies for some reason on my laptop the commands we not working properly (I probably need to do a reinstall) which is what I used to build your result and hence gave me the error, but I did build it with your result on my desktop and it worked perfectly (My desktop is what I used initially for my writing of the beamer presentation) I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Robert Don't worry, on your laptop, before re-installing, try to delete the auxiliary files and then compile with PDFLaTeX, Biber, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX.